# Node.js "FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory" -- possible to get a stack trace?

Tags: node.js

Well... I'm back to square one. I can't figure this out for the life of me.

I'm getting the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I could enumerate the dozens (yes, dozens) of things I've tried to get to the root of this problem, but really it would be far too much. So here are the key points:

- I can only get it to happen on my production server, and my app is large and complicated, so it is proving very difficult to isolate
- It happens even though heap size & RSS size are both < 200 Mb, which should not be a problem given that the machines (Amazon Cloud, CentOS, m1.large) have 8Gb RAM

**My assumption is that** (because of the 2nd point), a leak is probably not the cause; rather, it seems like there's probably a SINGLE object that is very large. The following thread backs up this theory:: [In Node.js using JSON.stringify results in 'process out of memory' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189940/in-node-js-using-json-stringify-results-in-process-out-of-memory-error)

What I really need is some way to find out what the state of the memory is at the moment the application crashes, or perhaps a stack trace leading up to the FATAL ERROR.

Based upon my assumption above, a 10-minute-old heap dump is insufficient (since the object would have not resided in memory).

Comment: Just making sure the basic bases have been covered. Are you sure the process is running with `ulimit` settings allowing it to use all that RAM? Do you know what's going into the app that could create a single object so large? Doesn't seem all that likely that the app is using < 200 MB RAM then a single event suddenly exhausts an additional 7.8 GB.

Comment: @PeterLyons ulimit is at 1024 (default). Btw, doesn't ulimit have to do with sockets/files, not RAM? Anyways, it's hard to say what could be creating an object so large; that's part of the mystery of this problem. I'm guessing that one (or more) users have something in their account that is unique which I did not predict or properly cap, but I can't even begin to guess where/what is is. As I said, it's a very large application.

Comment: ulimit can control many resources including open files, memory, CPU, processes, etc. See `ulimit -m` and `ulimit -d`  in particular http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html. It seems more realistic that the memory usage is spiking to 1 GB than 7 GB. I guess my next line of inquiry would be the largest requests the app is serving. Are clients streaming large uploads? Are there lots of concurrent clients sending in tons of requests? At least you can follow those clues into the codebase and add extra logging instrumentation.

Comment: You may also want to try setting ulimit artificially low in your dev environment in an attempt to force the problem to recur under easier-to-control circumstances.

Comment: I've capped the upload size via express @ 2mb. There are potentially many clients connecting, though, and the connections tend to be rather long lived. I just bumped the ulimit way up; we'll see how it goes I guess.

Comment: @PeterLyons Okay; I can confirm that increasing ulimit by 100x did not fix the problem...

Comment: I am facing this issue and my Linux server memory is 1GB. Might this be the reason?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have to give huge props to [Trevor Norris on this one for helping to modify node.js itself](https://github.com/trevnorris) such that it would automatically generate a heap dump when this error happened.

Ultimately what solved this problem for me, though, was much more mundane. I wrote some simple code that appended the endpoint of each incoming API request to a log file. I waited to gather ~10 data points (crashes) and compared the endpoints which had been run 60sec before the crash. I found that in 9/10 cases, a single endpoint that had been hit just before the crash.

From there, it was just a matter of digging deeper into the code. I pared everything down -- returning less data from my mongoDB queries, passing only necessary data from an object back to the callback, etc. Now we've gone 6x longer than average without a single crash on any of the servers, leading me to *hope* that it is resolved... for now.

Comment: I created an npm package that now contains this functionality: https://npmjs.org/package/ofe

Comment: and then open the heap dump file: Chrome dev tools -> Profiles -> Load

Answer (score 49):

Just because this is the top answer on Google at the moment, I figured I'd add a solution for a case I just ran across:

I had this issue using express with ejs templates - the issue was that I failed to close an ejs block, and the file was js code - something like this:

```
var url = '<%=getUrl("/some/url")'
/* lots more javascript that ejs tries to parse in memory apparently */
```

This is obviously a super specific case, OP's solution should be used the majority of the time. However, OP's solution would not work for this (ejs stack trace won't be surfaced by `ofe`).

Comment: You just saved me SO much time sir.. thank you for adding this. Was my case exactly, just had to track down the unclosed EJS tag.

Comment: I had <%= user.username => instead of <%= user.username %>... It took me a few days to find this -_-

Comment: same issuse with SailsJS + EJS

Answer (score 13):

**There is no single solution for this problem.**
I read different cases, most of them related to JS, but in my case, for example, was just a broken jade template loop that was infinite because of a code bug.

I guess is just a syntax error that node doesn't manage well.
Check your code or post it to find the problem.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was deploying Rails 4.2.1 via cap production deploy (capistrano) and during the assets precompile received:

rake stdout: rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
(execjs):1

I had run a dozen data imports via active_admin earlier and it appears to have used up all the RAM

**Solution:**  Server restart and deploy ran first time....

Comment: Did you come up with a long term solution for this? It's not sustainable to be restarting the server on each deploy. Thanks

Comment: A server restart fixed this issue for me too.

Comment: I was working on angular 4 universal with webpack, I was trying to prod build, but was getting this out of memory error on amazon ec2 server, Server reboot fixed my problem.

Comment: I was deploying a Rails 5 app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and running `eb deploy` in terminal gave me same error. Restarting servers on AWS EB console worked. Later deployed no problem

Answer (score 4):

Could it be a recursion issue on an object you are serializing, that is just large to begin with, and runs out of memory before recursion becomes an issue?

I created the [safe-clone-deep](https://www.npmjs.org/package/safe-clone-deep) npm module for this reason...  basically you'll want to do the following.

```
var clone = require('safe-clone-deep');
...
   return JSON.stringify(clone(originalObject));
```

This will allow you to clone pretty much any object that will then serialize safely.  Also, if one of the objects inherits from `Error` it will serialize the inherited `name`, `message` and `stack` properties, since these don't typically serialize.

Comment: I hit this problem in infinite recursion where I kept appending the same object to itself.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we had accidentally allocated a huge (sparse) array that caused util.format to blow up:

http://grahamrhay.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/fatal-error-js-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory/

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had initialised an associative array (Object) using []. As soon as I initialised it as {} the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a file I was using to seed the db during development was causing the leak. For some reason node didn't like a multi-line comment I had at the end of the file. I can't see anything wrong with it, but a process of elimination means I know it's this section of this file.

Answer (score 1):

Analysing a number of cases , the most common problem is that of an infinite loop . This would be difficult to solve in a complex app , that is where test driven development comes handy !!

Answer (score 1):

I spent few days to get to the root cause of the problem. The "JS - process out of memory" error started occurring during webpack build only in AWS EC2 instance. Build was successful in my local system though.
The reason was the following code:
Previous:
`import { ShoppingCartOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCartOutlined";`
It was fixed by:
`import ShoppingCartOutlined from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCartOutlined";`

It might help someone using material-ui/icons and ends up with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what happen here:

I lost some days with this problem, until I found that in some file I was importing a class from one static file, a builded file. It make the build process to never end. Something like:

```
import PropTypes from "../static/build/prop-types";
```

Fixing to the real source solved all the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using npm 5.0.3 on an AWS instance, we had permissions issues on the npm global folder itself which has probably caused this to happen to us.
we ran : `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
so I tried this:   node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
This works.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue while installing the node packages on a server using `npm i`.

```
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [npm]
 2: 0x556f73a6e011 [npm]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [npm]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [npm]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm]
 7: v8::internal::Heap::CollectAllGarbage(int, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm]
 8: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [npm]
 9: v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]
10: 0x159539b040bd
Aborted
```

My solution is to add additional flag

```
node --max-old-space-size=250 `which npm` i
```

Hope it saves time for someone

Answer (score 0):

Could be issue with node version.
I had same issue coming frequently while running react application. I was facing this issue with node version 14.7.2.Tried lots of solutions like increasing heap memory, clearing cache, re-installing node modules. None of it solved the issue. Finally, downgraded Node version to 10.24.1 and this stopped the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to secondary memory full. In my case it was due to Redis rdb file was very huge. something like below this is showing less size but at peak time it'll be like 4GB.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).