# FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed when try to publish npm module

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory, npm, publish, fatal-error

I'm trying to publish a module with:

```
npm publish ./
```

Following this gist: https://gist.github.com/coolaj86/1318304

But when I try to run this command I get the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

The npm process reaches 1.2 Gb in memory, but in my computer is more free ram, any ideas?

Comment: Something about your package is probably wrong if it uses that much memory

Comment: Something? for example? I only using express and mongojs packages to do some routing...

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616770/node-js-fatal-error-js-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory-possible may help.

Comment: Same here: Code available in [this](https://github.com/koinejs/Decorators) repo.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a huge ignored "tags" file in my root dir. It was 1.5Gb. I removed it and I was able to publish the package.

npm publish --dd provides some aditional info. I was able to check that the compressing was taking too long, which gave me the hint.