# React app won't start on "npm start" command - "process out of memory" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, npm

I have a React app that I'm trying to start via running `npm start`. This app currently is part of a Firebase project and using Firebase Cloud Functions as its backend, but previously was using a node server as the backend. When I was using the node server, I had no problems start the app and developing locally by running `npm run dev` in the node app and `npm start` in the React app. Somewhere along the way of transitioning from a node app to a Firebase app I am no longer able to start my React app locally, which I want to do to be able to develop locally. Here's the error I get in my console when I try running the command:

```
[28951:0x158008000]     4427 ms: Scavenge 66.2 (95.0) -> 56.5 (95.0) MB, 15.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: wasm code commit Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 0x1007ff344 node::Abort() [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x1007ff4c4 node::errors::TryCatchScope::~TryCatchScope() [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 3: 0x10091eb98 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 4: 0x10091eb2c v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 5: 0x100e572dc v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::AllocateForCodeInRegion(v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule*, unsigned long, v8::base::AddressRegion) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 6: 0x100e581b8 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::CreateEmptyJumpTableInRegion(unsigned int, v8::base::AddressRegion) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 7: 0x100e57680 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::AddCodeSpace(v8::base::AddressRegion) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 8: 0x100e57ff4 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::NativeModule(v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, bool, v8::internal::VirtualMemory, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::Counters>, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule>*) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
 9: 0x100e5a234 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeManager::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine*, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, unsigned long, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
10: 0x100e60b3c v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, unsigned long, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
11: 0x100e60a84 v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
12: 0x100e39464 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::CreateNativeModule(std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
13: 0x100e42178 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::PrepareAndStartCompile::RunInForeground(v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob*) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
14: 0x100e42a08 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::CompileTask::RunInternal() [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
15: 0x10085efa4 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::RunForegroundTask(std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::Task, std::__1::default_delete<v8::Task> >) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
16: 0x10085dfbc node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
17: 0x100fb3ac8 uv__async_io [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
18: 0x100fc5688 uv__io_poll [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
19: 0x100fb3f58 uv_run [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
20: 0x10083a8b4 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
21: 0x1007d9604 node::Start(int, char**) [/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node]
22: 0x182718f54 start [/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-site@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-site@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/salinawu/.npm/_logs/2021-01-19T07_02_03_221Z-debug.log
```

And here's the contents of the log file:

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v12.20.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~prestart: personal-site-backend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: personal-site-backend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: PATH: /Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/salinawu/projects/website/app/node_modules/.bin:/Users/salinawu/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/salinawu/projects/website/app
10 silly lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle personal-site-backend@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: personal-site-backend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid personal-site-backend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/salinawu/projects/website/app
16 verbose Darwin 20.1.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node" "/Users/salinawu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.20.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error personal-site-backend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the personal-site-backend@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm really unsure of how to approach this and why it's happening. I've tried deleting my node modules and cache and running `npm install`, but I get the same thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using ejs template, did you checked this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616770/node-js-fatal-error-js-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be an issue with downloading the `fsevents` package when running `npm install`, which was being pulled in by `react-scripts`. This was the error I was seeing:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@11.2.0 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
```

After trying the many suggestions listed in this issue (https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/246), I finally found my solution all the way at the bottom, which was to upgrade my `react-scripts` package version in my `package.json` file to `^3.4.3` (it was originally 2.1.8).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your memory limit reached by program. In windows you can extend your node memory limit in windows via:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=Value_In_MB
```

In Unix:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=Value_In_MB
```

Note: This is so specific problem. It may be related your OS, Device, Versions or etc. This approach may be saves the day.