# How to avoid Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

```
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
[98908:000001B2E3E77760]     9570 ms: Scavenge 15.5 (19.0) -> 15.3 (17.7) MB, 2.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure;
Error Worker terminated due to reaching memory limit: JS heap out of memory

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I have created a multi-threaded script and since I made some modification to my worker.js sometimes when I put too many threads at a time the program crashes with a memory limit error message.

I use pkg . to compile my js scripts in a single .exe how to increase the nodeJS limit

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616770/node-js-fatal-error-js-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory-possible

Comment: dont have solution in my case