# NodeJS: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, heap-memory

I have a VPS (Debian) with 2 GB RAM where I run `pm2` in order to execute a node.js server application. I have a cache and every night, at 3 am I want to dump it into a file as a backup.

Every day at 3, I got the following error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [717119:0x63345b0] 66921944 ms: Mark-sweep 956.0 (1043.7) -> 954.9
> (1043.7) MB, 737.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 0.349)
> allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed [717119:0x63345b0]
> 66922975 ms: Mark-sweep 962.8 (1043.7) -> 961.9 (1059.7) MB, 978.0 /
> 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.052) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory  1: 0xb6e500 node::Abort() [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 2: 0xa7e632  [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 3: 0xd47f20 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 4: 0xd482c7
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 5: 0xf25685  [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 6: 0xf37b6d
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/stoc> 7:
> 0xf1226e
> v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/userName/web/app> 8:
> 0xf13637
> v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/userName/web/stoc> 9:
> 0xef3b80 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 10: 0xeeb5f4
> v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/userName/web/stoc>11:
> 0xeed988
> v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType) [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 12: 0x131ddec v8::internal::IncrementalStringBuilder::Extend() [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 13: 0x10349d8
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)
> [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 14: 0x1035c52 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>15:
> 0x10378af v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>16:
> 0x10378af v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>17:
> 0x10378af v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>18:
> 0x10378af v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>19:
> 0x10378af v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>20:
> 0x10378af v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/di>21:
> 0x1037f13
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeJSReceiverSlow(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>)
> [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 22: 0x1039897 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
> v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /home/d>23:
> 0x103ae5f v8::internal::JsonStringify(v8::internal::Isolate*,
> v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,
> v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node /hom>24: 0xdcdbf7
> v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, unsigned long*,
> v8::internal::Isolate*) [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]
> 25: 0x16e9af9  [node
> /home/userName/web/appName.com/public_html/appNameServer/appNameServer.js]

I know the error is straight forward and the trivial answer would be to add more RAM, but I still want to share some more data:

1. Before the crash, the app consumed 640mb (gross), meaning the cache itself consumes less than that.
2. When I run this `node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'` the result is 1662.
3. When I run the caching dump locally, it takes around 3 seconds to export the items but viewing pm2 logs on the server, it takes 14 seconds between trying to export the cache items until the server is back up again, as if the export takes much longer or maybe the crash/restart takes that much, not sure.

> 2022-12-27T03:00:00.016Z: exporting to json 2|appName|

> 2022-12-27T03:00:14.747Z: server is running on https at port...

Based on the numbers above, 640mb (gross) and the fact that there's at least one more 1gb left for node, I don't understand why there's a heap out of memory in the first place.

Please advise, thanks

Comment: Have you tried to increase the amount of heap for Node?

Comment: I thought that giving it 1.6gb out of the 2gb should be enough with the numbers I've seen. If I knew why it still crashes, I'd know how much more I can give it, assuming I can add more without crashing the vps itself.

Answer (score 3):

## NODE_OPTIONS (--max_old_space_size)

In my case

```
$ node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'
4144
```

but

```
$ export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 && node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'
8240
```

so maybe you can modify amount of available memory using this variable.

## Writing file using buffer

Probably you are writing file using

```
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/test.txt', content);
```

but maybe you can switch to

```
fs.createWriteStream(path, [options])
```

then you will not have to store all content of file in memory in the same time.

## Profiling using IDE

I solved similar cases using tools like this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/v8-cpu-and-memory-profiling.html#ws_node_cpu_profiling

in console you can simply start your script with `--porf` flag. It will created huge, hard to read, but very detailed logs telling about memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you for your tips: 1. I have 2gb memory (+512 swap), how much --max_old_space_size=? I can define without blowing up the server? 2. It crashes before saving the file but I will definitely check your tip about using a buffer. 3. Locally it works and it takes less than 3 seconds to export so profiling locally won't help here.

Comment: Regarding point 2, you mean to create the file by reading the cache as a stream reader without first exporting the cache to the memory and then save it?

Comment: I realized that stringify(ing) the json before writing to a file is the problem because (I guess) it's duplicating the json content thus duplicating the memory it requires.

Comment: There are some formats of files which can be written byte after byte, or line by line (like csv) without having all file content loaded to memory. Unfortunately for json it is a little harder to skip memory consuming "stringify" process, but it is still possible. Check library 'json-write' https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-write mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189940/in-node-js-using-json-stringify-results-in-process-out-of-memory-error